# subset after a match occurs

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this (specifically the data.frame contains 50 columns):

> ```
>   "G1"            "G2"  
>   SEP11          ABCC1   
>   0.1365         0.1858   
>   214223_at      ADAM19     
>   0.1305         0.131   
>   COPS4          BIK 
>   0.1271         0.1143
>   ACE            ALG3
>   0.1333         0.119
>   EMP3           GGH
>   0.1246         0.1214
> ```

and another data.frame like this(specifically the data.frame contains 50 columns):

> ```
>    "G1"           "G2"  
>   0.1365         0.1858   
>   0.1271         0.1143    
>   0.1246         0.1214
> ```

I would like the following output:

> ```
>   "G1"           "G2"  
>  SEP11          ABCC1  
>  0.1365         0.1858  
>  COPS4          BIK     
>  0.1271         0.1143   
>  EMP3           GGH
>  0.1246         0.1214
> ```

Can anyone help me please?

Basically, after R find the match between "0.1365" in the data.frame 1 and "0.1365" in the data.frame2  it will extract the corresponding name from the data.frame1 associated to that number for which the match exist and the number too because I would like to answer the question: which element from the data.frame1 is associated to that number?

Comment: hi Roland, sorry, but I thought it was confounding due to many edit I done.

Comment: It is not clear if only values from the first column need to match or if all values in a row need to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- read.table(text=" G1            G2  
  SEP11          ABCC1   
  0.1365         0.1858   
  214223_at      ADAM19     
  0.1305         0.131   
  COPS4          BIK 
  0.1271         0.1143
  ACE            ALG3
  0.1333         0.119
  EMP3           GGH
  0.1246         0.1214",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text="G1           G2  
      0.1365         0.1858   
      0.1271         0.1143    
      0.1246         0.1214 
 ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#separate names and numbers
df1a <- df1[seq(from=1,to=nrow(df1)-1,by=2),]
df1b <- df1[seq(from=2,to=nrow(df1),by=2),]

#look up and merge again
df <- rbind(df1b[apply(df1b,1,paste,collapse=",") %in% apply(df2,1,paste,collapse=","),],
            df1a[apply(df1b,1,paste,collapse=",") %in% apply(df2,1,paste,collapse=","),])
df <- df[order(as.numeric(rownames(df))),]
#       G1     G2
#1   SEP11  ABCC1
#2  0.1365 0.1858
#5   COPS4    BIK
#6  0.1271 0.1143
#9    EMP3    GGH
#10 0.1246 0.1214
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are in pairs of rows, this should work:

1. Your data:

   ```
   df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '  "G1"            "G2"
                     SEP11          ABCC1
                     0.1365         0.1858
                     214223_at      ADAM19
                     0.1305         0.131
                     COPS4          BIK
                     0.1271         0.1143
                     ACE            ALG3
                     0.1333         0.119
                     EMP3           GGH
                     0.1246         0.1214')
   df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = ' "G1"           "G2"
                     0.1365         0.1858
                     0.1271         0.1143
                     0.1246         0.1214 ')
   ```
2. Matching the specified data and the data from the previous row

   ```
   myMatch <- which(df1$G1 %in% df2$G1)
   myMatch <- sort(c(myMatch, myMatch-1))
   ```
3. The subsetting.

   ```
   df1[myMatch, ]
   #        G1     G2
   # 1   SEP11  ABCC1
   # 2  0.1365 0.1858
   # 5   COPS4    BIK
   # 6  0.1271 0.1143
   # 9    EMP3    GGH
   # 10 0.1246 0.1214
   ```

#### Update

Borrowing a little from Roland's approach, if you are trying to match across multiple columns, then indeed `merge` might be a more appropriate approach. Unfortunately, your data is not currently in a form that allows for easy merging, but that's also easily fixed:

1. "Fix" your "df1" `data.frame` by separating out the names and values and `cbind`ing the output.

   ```
   df1.new <- cbind(df1[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(df1), by = 2), ], 
                    df1[seq(from = 2, to = nrow(df1), by = 2), ])
   ```
2. Rename the columns for the first half of the data to indicate that they are names. The columns for the second half of the data will be retained for merging.

   ```
   names(df1.new)[1:(ncol(df1.new)/2)] <- 
     paste(names(df1.new[1:(ncol(df1.new)/2)]), "Name", sep = ".")
   df1.new
   #     G1.Name G2.Name     G1     G2
   # 1     SEP11   ABCC1 0.1365 0.1858
   # 3 214223_at  ADAM19 0.1305  0.131
   # 5     COPS4     BIK 0.1271 0.1143
   # 7       ACE    ALG3 0.1333  0.119
   # 9      EMP3     GGH 0.1246 0.1214
   ```
3. Use `merge()` to get your "subset" of data.

   ```
   merge(df1.new, df2)
   #       G1     G2 G1.Name G2.Name
   # 1 0.1246 0.1214    EMP3     GGH
   # 2 0.1271 0.1143   COPS4     BIK
   # 3 0.1365 0.1858   SEP11   ABCC1
   ```

This "wider" `data.frame` might be more convenient for you to use in general.